# unlockAccount on "Mist" is not allowed

Tags: web3js, mist

I am trying to use my Dapp application on Mist but when I tried to unlock the account to execute a transaction I receive the message **"Method "personal_unlockAccount" not allowed."**

the code:

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8546"));
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0xfe....fe'), password, 5)
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.error)
```

The exact same code works if I am using the geth with WebSocket.

I am using Web3js version 1.0.0 beta 18

All other operations that does not requires an unlocked account works perfectly on both environment (web browser with WebSocket and Mist with the givenProvider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that using Metamask, Mist or any web3 browser they have your own unlock implementation.

I have to just call a transaction and these implementation will be asking for unlocking.

So, there is no need to call the unlock.